# 2D Array not printing the correct output

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to initialise a 2D Array in C filled with X's except for the index (2,2) which will be filled with the letter 'C'. However, when I run the code below, not only do I get a 'C' at (2,2) but for some reason, I also end up getting a 'C' at the index (1,9) (see output below).

I tried changing the width and height values and realised that it works sometimes. For example, when I make height = 10 and width = 10, I get the correct output with only one 'C' in its proper slot.

I'm quite new to C programming and have no idea why it's producing the correct output sometimes. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
int width = 10;
int height = 7;
int x = 2;
int y =2;
int limit = 3;

//initialising 2D array
char board[width][height];
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){//rows
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){//cols
        if(i == y && j == x){
            board[y][x] = 'C';
        }
        else{
            board[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
//printing 2D array
for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){//rows
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){//cols
        printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Since it's an array of `char`, you may as well just do: `memset(board, 'X', width * height); board[y][x] = 'C';`

Comment: Do you just want 'C' in a few positions while the rest are 'X'? If so, _memset ()_ might be better. Use it to set all the values to 'X' then use conditionals to set specific values in the array to something else.

Comment: In the future, always copy paste the output _as text_. Don't use an image for displaying text.

Comment: Thanks for pro tip. Will try that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the array declaration wrong.
Instead of

```
char board[width][height];
```

you need

```
char board[height][width];
/*          Rows    Cols  */
```

Comment: Ahh cheers mate. I knew I overlooked something simple. Thanks :)